# Not able to remove MultiIndex in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dataframe `df` with below structure. I tried `df.reset_index() to remove multiIndex. But its not working.

```
   df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
   print(df.columns)

   MultiIndex(levels=[['MID Index', 'RLG Index', 'RLV Index', 'RTY Index', 'S5COND Index', 'S5CONS Index', 'S5ENRS Index', 'S5FINL Index', 'S5HLTH Index', 'S5INDU Index', 'S5INFT Index', 'S5MATR Index', 'S5RLST Index', 'S5TELS Index', 'S5UTIL Index', 'SPX Index', 'date'], ['LP', 'PX', '']],
       labels=[[16, 7, 7, 15, 15, 0, 0, 8, 8, 3, 3, 9, 9, 2, 2, 10, 10, 1, 1, 11, 11, 12, 12, 4, 4, 13, 13, 5, 5, 14, 14, 6, 6], [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],
       names=['ticker', 'field'])
```

If not able to remove the multiIndex, atleast i need to the re-order the columns based on column names. I tried above code for re-ordering,but its not working.
Can anyone please help me

Attaching the input [Dataframe file `df`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PAJj2_oq0VTWrU-jTeuBcN4gDzvS0Rl3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you input df.head() ?

Comment: Hi Wen. I have attached the dataframe head values in excel sheet

Comment: See my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print(df)

```
Out[35]: 
user_id  a     s      
session  b  b  C  b  C
revenue -1  0  1  2  1
```

Op1

```
df.columns=df.columns.map('_'.join)
df
Out[37]: 
         a_b  a_b  s_C  s_b  s_C
revenue   -1    0    1    2    1
```

Op2

```
df.T.reset_index()
Out[41]: 
  user_id session  revenue
0       a       b       -1
1       a       b        0
2       s       C        1
3       s       b        2
4       s       C        1
```

Then do the following calculation you need

Data Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['a','a','s','s','s'],
                    'session':['b','b','C','b','C'],
                    'revenue':[-1,0,1,2,1]})
df=df.set_index(['user_id','session']).T
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks a lot Wen!

Comment: @ArvinthKumar Yw happy holiday